# Reference Request : For a paper on resolving conflicts in Interpretability methods

Tags: reference-request, machine-learning, ai.artificial-intel

Well , this post is going to sound a bit similar to crush pages , where people post where and when they had seen someone and ask other people if they can help in identifying that person or this post can seem something like the post in  :

https://movies.stackexchange.com/

So, a few weeks ago , I came across a paper through a tweet,released recently about resolving conflicts between interpretability methods. The title had the word 'attribute' in it. I am trying to find the paper but I am unable to locate it.

I generally like Tweets to be able to retrieve later and I probably missed liking this tweet. To the best of my memory, I came across it through a Tweet by a phd student at MIT working on explainable AI. Unfortunately,I am unable to find her in my following list as well.

If I recall correctly , two of the methods being studied in the paper were LIME and SHAP. It would be a great help if someone could identify the paper or the tweet. Thanks

Edit : Thanks ,I found the paper :

https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.02958.pdf

Comment: The question as such will not be useful to anyone else in the future. Maybe you should delete it?